# Replacement of Dataframe column by value_counts() of that column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Im just trying to replace columns of DataframeGroupBy objects by their pd.df.value_counts(). I just cant find out how to do it, my now closest solution looks like this:

`df_grouped = df.groupby('class')
for group,group_df in df_grouped:
    for column in group_df:
        df_grouped[column] = df_grouped[column].value_counts().tolist()`

throwing out:

`TypeError: 'DataFrameGroupBy' object does not support item assignment`

I would like to just replace every column of the different groups by their value_counts().

Thanks for the help in advance

Comment: This might help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46863602/find-value-counts-within-a-pandas-dataframe-of-strings/46863713#46863713

Comment: If the above link is not what you are looking for do add a sample data and expected output

Comment: Use GroupBy.transform (http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.transform.html). If you share sample data we can give you more specific help.

Comment: I basically just have a 150x5 dataframe. there seemed not to be a efficient way to just replace every column by its value_counts(), so ill leave it here and just use a 2nd dataframe containing all appended value_counts() results.