# Python pandas count occurrences in each column

Tags: python, pandas

I am new to pandas. Can someone help me in calculating frequencies of values for each columns.

Dataframe:

```
id|flag1|flag2|flag3|  
---------------------
1 |  1  |   2 |   1 |  
2 |  3  |   1 |   1 |  
3 |  3  |   4 |   4 |  
4 |  4  |   1 |   4 |  
5 |  2  |   3 |   2 |
```

I want something like

```
id|flag1|flag2|flag3|  
---------------------
1 |  1  |   2 |   2 |  
2 |  1  |   1 |   1 |  
3 |  2  |   1 |   0 |  
4 |  1  |   1 |   2 |
```

Explanation - id 1 has 1 value in flag1, 2 values in flag2 and 2 values in flag3.

Comment: why `id` 5 should be ignored? The last line could be `5|0|0|0`

Comment: id is not used, that is why it is ignored. values in column do not represent that they belong to a specific id, they represent numbers and I have to categorise on basis of those numbers

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First filter only `flag` columns by [`filter`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.filter.html) or removing `id` column and then [`apply`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.apply.html) function [`value_counts`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.value_counts.html), last replace `NaN`s to `0` and cast to `int`s:

```
df = df.filter(like='flag').apply(lambda x: x.value_counts()).fillna(0).astype(int)
print (df)
   flag1  flag2  flag3
1      1      2      2
2      1      1      1
3      2      1      0
4      1      1      2
```

Or:

```
df = df.drop('id', 1).apply(lambda x: x.value_counts()).fillna(0).astype(int)
print (df)
   flag1  flag2  flag3
1      1      2      2
2      1      1      1
3      2      1      0
4      1      1      2
```

Thank you, [Bharath](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47390407/python-pandas-count-occurences-in-each-column/47390569?noredirect=1#comment81735907_47390569) for suggestion:

```
df = df.filter(like='flag').apply(pd.Series.value_counts()).fillna(0).astype(int)
```

Comment: Sir you dont need `lambda` here  you can use `pd.Series.value_counts`, used here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46863602/find-value-counts-within-a-pandas-dataframe-of-strings/46863713#46863713