# Word count of single column in pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

Here is my attempt at a word count for a single column using `group by` with pandas :

First setup the data :

```
columns = ['col1','col2','col3']
data = np.array([['word1','word2','word3'] , ['word1','word5','word3'], ['word3','word7','word3']])
to_count = pd.DataFrame(data,columns=columns)
```

I'm attempting to count words in `col1` in `to_count`.

`to_count` contains :

```
    col1   col2   col3
0  word1  word2  word3
1  word1  word5  word3
2  word3  word7  word3
```

To count the words I then use :

```
print(to_count.groupby('col1').count())
```

which displays :

```
col2  col3
col1             
word1     2     2
word3     1     1
```

This seems partly correct in that the word counts are returned but they are spread across multiple columns. How to access word count for a single column ?
I could just access a single column in the word count dataframe but this does not seem correct.

Comment: This might also help - https://stackoverflow.com/q/46863602/4800652

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, I think this is what you're looking for:

```
print(to_count.groupby('col1')['col1'].count())
```

Output:

```
       col1
word1    2
word3    1
```

Answer (score 1):

You can apply value_counts() fn to one column of dataframe. Following applies it all columns one by one:

```
for onecol in to_count:
    print(onecol, ":\n", to_count[onecol].value_counts())
```

Output:

```
col1 :
word1    2
word3    1
Name: col1, dtype: int64
col2 :
word5    1
word2    1
word7    1
Name: col2, dtype: int64
col3 :
word3    3
Name: col3, dtype: int64
```

Answer (score 1):

How about this:

**Single column:**

```
df['col1'].value_counts()
```

will return:

```
word1    2
word3    1
```

**All columns:**

```
df.apply(lambda col: col.value_counts()).fillna(0).astype(int)
```

will return:

```
       col1  col2  col3
word1     2     0     0
word2     0     1     0
word3     1     0     3
word5     0     1     0
word7     0     1     0
```

---

Copy & paste example:

```
from io import StringIO
import pandas as pd

data = """
    col1   col2   col3
0  word1  word2  word3
1  word1  word5  word3
2  word3  word7  word3
"""

df = pd.read_table(StringIO(data), sep='\s+')

print(df['col1'].value_counts())
print(df.apply(lambda col: col.value_counts().astype(int)).fillna(0).astype(int))
```